# How to convert a Horizontal Menu with vertical submenus into a Vertical Accordion menu with submenus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to make my menu so that when I am at a certain window size, like on mobile, my menu will convert to a vertical drop down accordion menu. I am familiar with media queries and responsive/adaptive designs, but I can't get my submenu to vertically drop/slide down, either on hover or click.

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RK_MediArt/2KvLv/2/)

HTML:

```
<!--MENU UNDER HEADER BEGINS-->
<table id="menubar" width="0" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
  <tr>
     <td> 

     <div id="navmenu"> <!--#navmenu DIV menu contents start here-->
     <ul> 

<li>    
    <a href="index.php" class="mainlist">HOME</a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="about.php" class="mainlist">ABOUT ME</a>
</li>




<li class="slidedown">    
    <a href="graphicdesign.php" class="mainlist">GRAPHIC DESIGN</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="graphicdesign/hobbyist-independent.php">Hobbyist/Independent</a></li>    
    <li><a href="graphicdesign/job&amp;freelance.php">Job & FreeLance</a></li>
    <li><a href="graphicdesign/universityatbuffalo.php">University At Buffalo</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>


<li class="slidedown"> 
    <a href="webdesign.php" class="mainlist">WEB DESIGN</a>
    <ul>
    <li>Hobbyist/Independent</li>
    <li>Job & FreeLance</li>
    <li>University At Buffalo Website</a></li> 
    </ul>
</li>


<li class="slidedown">
    <a href="photography.php" class="mainlist">PHOTOGRAPHY</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="photography/hobbyist-independent.php">Hobbyist/Independent</a></li>
    <li><a href="photography/job&amp;freelance.php">Job & Freelance</a></li>
    <li><a href="photography/studentprojects.php">Student Projects</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>


<li>
    <a href="contactme.php" class="mainlist">CONTACT ME</a>
</li>

    </ul>
    </div> <!--#navmenu DIV menu contents end here-->

    </td>
  </tr>
</table> 
<!--menu under header ends-->
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:hidde;
  margin:auto;
}
#wrap {
  margin:auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: url(style/flourish-bg.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
  background-position: top center;
  z-index:0;
}
#header {
    width:1024px; 
    height:160px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#bgheader {
  background-image: url(style/bgheader.jpg);
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  height:160px;
}   
body {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background:#000;
}

/*----------MENU-----------*/


/*main menu*/

a:link {color:#fff; text-decoration:none;}
a:visited {color: #868D65;}
a:hover {color:#000;}
a:active {color: #868D65;}

#navmenu {
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
}

/*holds the listed items on main menu*/
#navmenu ul {
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style:none;
  text-decoration:none;
}

/*keeps main menu horiztonal, and effects the actualy list items, overrides any other menu float*/
#navmenu li {
  float:left;   
  padding: 30px 7px; 
  position:relative;
  list-style:none; 
  text-decoration:none;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size:12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top: 2px solid  #868D65;
  border-bottom: 2px solid  #868D65;
  transition: border-radius 1s, background 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-border-radius 1s, background 1s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-border-radius 1s, background 1s;
  z-index:200;
}

/*menu styling for hover, WHEN IMAGE IS ADDED, IT APPLIES TO ALL HOVER ACTIONS ON EVERY MENU*/
#navmenu li:hover {
  background: #eee;
  background-image: url(style/bgheader.jpg); 
  transition: border-radius 1s, background 1s;
 -moz-transition: -moz-border-radius 1s, background 1s;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-border-radius 1s, background 1s;
 z-index:200;
}
/*SUB MENU STARTS*/


/*this hides the submenu*/
#navmenu  li ul {
  position: absolute;
  top:75px;
  visibility:hidden;
  padding-left:0px;
}
/*this shows the submenu on hover over main menu*/
#navmenu  li:hover ul {visibility:visible;}

/*sub menu styling*/
#navmenu li ul li {
  float:none;
  width: 160px;
  font-size:12px;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 15px 5px 10px 5px;
  background: #222222;
  border: 1px solid #FFF; 
  color: #FFF;
  position:relative;
  margin-left: -6px;
}

/*sub menu styling for hover*/
#navmenu li ul li:hover {
  font-size:12px; 
  color: #000; 
  background-color: #868D65;
}
```

Comment: sorry guys, i am getting the hang of this posting stuff, very specific, I'm working on it.

Comment: Please include code directly into the question. A JSfiddle can be handy, but isn't permanent. Mark up code by putting 4 spaces in front of it (for blocks) or inline by surrounding it with backticks.

Comment: hmm, not having the best of luck here..in the preview it will show it's linked then when I think I got it right, it doesn't post correctly. i apologize.

Comment: thank you! katie and erik, i feel like i shouldn't even ask a question lol. i gotta get that straight next time. much appreciated

Comment: @RK_MediArt No problem.  Now you have a good example of a question format, because you can still edit your question and see how I've posted it.  (I'm terrible at CSS but it looked like it was a good question that needed a little code love :)

Comment: thank you erik, man the past two months I have really been putting a lot of work in, when it comes to building a website, my brain gets so overwhelmed, but I like to make things look good and i am a graphic designer trying to sharpen my skills with web design, however i am trying to learn fundamentals and important aspects so that when i encounter an issue i know which code does what etc and what methods and techniques are  best to use.. so  i just had to post a question like this because it has been challenging for me, and i know this is the right and best crowd to ask for live help.

Comment: haha thanks cody, better to be straight to the point, so thanks...was my very first post, so thought i'd add some extra details... again thank you,,, gettin anxious to see the a solution or see solutions! =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/8z9q9/1/)

```
@media (max-width:600px) {
  tr td #navmenu li {
    width:100%; // makes each item takes up the whole screen
  }
  tr td #navmenu li ul {
    position:relative !important; // removes the position absolute so that it doesn't overlap the higher up menu items
    top:0; // puts it right next to the menu item
    display:none; // so there is no unnecessary white space when the `li` isn't being hovered over
  }
  tr td #navmenu li:hover ul {
    display:block; // shows the submenu when you hover over the higher `li`s
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much cody! I will implement this! thanks a lot!

Comment: oh I definitely will! i was messing around with the settings on this to see how that worked., but definitely will once i reach that 15 reputation hehe!, thank you very much! simple code so powerful!,

Comment: CSS is a beautiful creation!

Comment: it definitely is...there is no way I can do something and achieve something when building a website and not keep practicing it...you guys here are a big help! i watch youtube tutorials alot, dig into websites, forums, people sharing here and there, but for me it's important to understand why it all works, and i do so on my website, i want to make sure i have all the fundamentals down, and this is definitely the perfect place to get that help...need that group help from experts on stackoverflow.com! so again thanks cody!

Answer (score 1):

put something like this in your mobile layout's media query

```
#navmenu li {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  float:none;   
}

#navmenu  li ul {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top:0;
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

since your technique on how to show submenu is purely css (:hover on parent and visibility:visible), we need js/jquery because our child menu is display:none now

```
$('li.slidedown').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('ul').slideDown();
}, function() {
  $(this).find('ul').slideUp();
});
```

havent checked my codes, byt i hope you got my point

Comment: thanks bondy!, I will take a look at this, I would have to add this to my attached .js file and make those css edits and give it a shot, thank you very much!

Comment: once i check this out, i will let you know how it goes bondy, thanks again.. ill let you know if i have any complications.

Comment: was up bondy, okay i got it to work, thank you very much! works pretty smooth!... do you have a solution for click? I know it has something to do with .toggle or with mouse events, but how do i implement click/tap for touch screens when it reaches a certain window size

Comment: i find myself having to hold down my main menu items in order for my submenus to pop out trying to avoid going to that main menu items page because those are also links, maybe if I make an extra submenu item for each main menu and put something like "About Graphic Design", for example to make it easier on clicking?